# Trying to put assoociative array back into a flat text file saved as a .csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have created a script that will take a flat text file with 4 bits of information, with commas separating the 4 bits of information, as if it were a csv file, (and I've saved it as such), and it  will explode this file into an array, sort the information based on a number (the age of persons), from highest to lowest, and after that I don't have a solution for finishing the script. What I need is to rewrite this array back into the flat file again, now that the information has been properly sorted.

I was thinking either a rewrite or an implode of some kind.

The array looks as such:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => john
            [age] => 58
            [job] => inspector
            [salary] => 42000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => henry
            [age] => 49
            [job] => supervisor
            [salary] => 38000
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => monica
            [age] => 27
            [job] => assistant
            [salary] => 29000
        )


)
```

The actual code on my page looks like this:

```
?php>

$fh = fopen("C:xampp/htdocs/warehouseemplyees.csv", "r");

while(!feof($fh)){
    $current = trim(fgets($fh));
    $iArray[] = explode(",", $current);
}
$count = count($iArray);
for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
    $newArray[$x]["name"] = $iArray[$x][0];
    $newArray[$x]["age"] = $iArray[$x][1];
    $newArray[$x]["job"] = $iArray[$x][2];
    $newArray[$x]["salary"] = $iArray[$x][3];
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['age'] == $b['age']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['age'] > $b['age']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($newArray, "cmp");


?>
```

In the saved flat csv text file, the results look like this:

```
john,58,inspector,42000
henry,49,supervisor,38000
monica,27,assistant,29000
```

To conclude. So, once again, I just need to be able to put these results back into the file after this function has sorted them by age highest to lowest. This code works great by the way and the results can be seen in my localhost, but need to get the results back into the file. Thanks for your help. 
And please, if you would, be specific with me, I'm very new to programming, and it would help if you told me where to put my specific pieces of information into your code. I can't understand the generic descriptions people often use when talking code. So, if my specific array name goes somewhere or other specific name, please take the time to tell me because I won't know what specific changes to make for my specific application. Please take the necessary pieces from my code above and fill it into your solution so that I'll know. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh = fopen("C:xampp/htdocs/warehouseemplyees.csv", "r");

while(!feof($fh)){
    $current = trim(fgets($fh));
    $iArray[] = explode(",", $current);
}
// You're done reading here
fclose ($fh);
$count = count($iArray);
for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
    $newArray[$x]["name"] = $iArray[$x][0];
    $newArray[$x]["age"] = $iArray[$x][1];
    $newArray[$x]["job"] = $iArray[$x][2];
    $newArray[$x]["salary"] = $iArray[$x][3];
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['age'] == $b['age']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['age'] > $b['age']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($newArray, "cmp");

// Reopen your file to overwrite with new content : "w". I guess it's the part you were looking for ?
$fh = fopen("C:xampp/htdocs/warehouseemplyees.csv", "w");

foreach ($newArray as $line) {
  fputcsv ($fh, $line); 
}
fclose ($fh);
```

You might want to give a look at `fputcsv` to understand the reading part, then read about `fgetcsv` to understand how you could have designed your reading part easily.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Hello, I tried to give this answer the BIG GREEN CHECK MARK, but it said I'm too new to access that. So I will give one to you here. Thanks for your help, the code works perfectly. I'm looking forward to reading the reference material you suggested as well. I'd have to say that out of all the programming languages I've discovered so far, PHP is definitely my favorite. Everyone, please feel free to use this code if you need to, it works great! Cheers. :)